# Intergrating life of player in each level in unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

In my game there are various levels
I have made those level in separate scenes
Every Scene has a player at the starting point and when it crosses the exit point the next level (next scene) is loaded but the health and life are reset as starting point in the game and not remain what the player currently has when he exited the level

**Exit level Script:-**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExitLevel : MonoBehaviour {

    public string scene;
    private Player player;



    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        player = GameObject.Find ("Player").GetComponent<Player> ();
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D target){

                        if (target.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
            if (player.ArtifactCount == 1) {
                player.ArtifactCount = 0;
                                Destroy (target.gameObject);
                                Application.LoadLevel (scene);
                        }
                }
    }
}
```

**LifeMeter Script:-**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class LifeMeter : MonoBehaviour {

    public float Life = 100;
    public float maxLife = 100;
    public float LifeBurnRate = 1f;
    public Texture2D bgTexture;
    public Texture2D LifeBarTexture;
    public Texture2D HeartTexture;
    public int iconWidth = 32;
    public Vector2 LifeOffset = new Vector2(255, 10);
    public int HeartCount = 3;
    public Vector2 HeartOffset = new Vector2(455, 6.5f);
    public int HeartDistance = 0;
    public int HeartDistanceAddup = 40;
    public int HeartDisplayWidth = 40;
    public int HeartDisplayHeight = 40;


    private Player player;
    private ExitLevel exitLevel;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        player = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Player> ();
    }

    public void OnGUI(){
        var percent = Mathf.Clamp01 (Life / maxLife);

        if (!player) 
                percent = 0;

        if(Life == 0 && HeartCount !=0 ){
            HeartCount = HeartCount - 1;
            Life = 100;
        }
        HeartDistance = 0;
        DrawMeter (LifeOffset.x, LifeOffset.y, LifeBarTexture, bgTexture, percent);

        for (int i = 0; HeartCount > i; i++) {
            HeartDistance = HeartDistance + HeartDistanceAddup;
            GUI.DrawTexture (new Rect (HeartOffset.x + HeartDistance, HeartOffset.y, HeartDisplayWidth, HeartDisplayHeight), HeartTexture);
                }
    }

    void DrawMeter(float x, float y, Texture2D texture, Texture2D background, float percent){
        var bgW = background.width;
        var bgH = background.height;

        GUI.DrawTexture (new Rect (x, y, bgW, bgH), background);

        var nW = ((bgW - iconWidth) * percent) + iconWidth;

        GUI.BeginGroup (new Rect (x, y, nW, bgH));
        GUI.DrawTexture (new Rect (0, 0, bgW, bgH), texture);
        GUI.EndGroup ();



    }

    // Update is called once per frame
     void Update () {

        }


    public void life(){
    Life = Life - LifeBurnRate;

        if (HeartCount == 0) {
            {   Explode script = player.GetComponent<Explode> ();
        script.OnExplode ();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Since you look up the player details in the `Start` method for both classes shown here, store the life details in `Player`. That way, it'll persist across scenes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to proceed in the above case:

- You can add `DontDestroyOnload(this);` to your player object. This
  will not destroy that game object when the new level loads. And On
  Every start of level you can spawn him your level start point. This
  way your player's stats will remain consistent throughout the game.
- You can use a static class to get the players health and other
  required stats. Save the players health in the static class while
  exiting the level and apply the values to the next levels player
  object when the next level loads.

Comment: i added DontDestroyOnload(this); but how will i then make the same player renter the next scene?

Comment: In the next scene there is a new player in start point but i want to add the health stat of the previous level to it

Comment: Did it with Static variable

Answer (score 5):

you can use PlayerPrefs (Stores and accesses player preferences between game sessions)for save current status of Player.
Reffer this link http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html